# Traefik - cannot show dashboard

Tags: traefik

Treafik redirecting works like charm!

How can I configure the **Traefik dashboard** to be shown?

I have an "A"-record pointing to my domain and a CNAME record "monitor" pointing to the same domain. **Is this correct?**

My first attempt was this `docker-compose.yml file`. It contains also a Spring Boot application listening at 8080:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    command: --api --docker
    restart: always
    networks:
      - geosolutionsnet
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/ec2-user/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /home/ec2-user/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=geosolutionsnet"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.xyz.nl"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"
      #- "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=15768000"
```

With the browser I pointed to 'monitor.xyz.nl' but I got a 404.

My second try was with:

```yaml
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:xyz.nl;Path:/monitor"
```

Pointing my browser to xyz.nl/monitor ... gave again a 404.

My `traefik.toml` file is:

```toml
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
    
[docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  domain = "xyz.nl"
  watch = true
  exposedByDefault = false
  
[acme]
  email = "jj@xyz.nl"
  storage = "acme.json"
  onHostRule = true
  entryPoint = "https"
  onDemand = false
  [acme.tlsChallenge]
```

**UPDATE**:
Using the CNAME `traefik` that is mapped to domain `xyz.nl/traefik` results in a 404 error.

Using the CNAME 'monitor' pointing to the (A-record) domain I get the same result. I think that is normal because I configured the host match via a pathprefix.

Comment: try adding label ` - "traefik.backend=traefik" `?

Comment: Tx. Does not show the dashboard.

Comment: Add `- "8080"` as ports should solve the problem

Comment: Alas this won't help. Please see my update about A-records and CNAMES in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Docker compose I added to the traefik part port 8080:8080.

Then, the Traefik dashboard was shown by navigating to port 8080. Important is to navigate via 'http' and **NOT** 'https'.

The next improvement is by using HTTPS so that no unfriendly people can visit the Traefik dashboard.

Comment: Those looking to set-up the Traefik dashboard to use HTTPS see Reaction Commerce's [proxy-traefik](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/proxy-traefik) for a working example. Note HTTPS will not prevent _adversaries_ from accessing your dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    networks:
      - geosolutionsnet
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/ec2-user/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /home/ec2-user/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=geosolutionsnet"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:xyz.nl;PathPrefix:/monitor" # <----
      - "traefik.port=8080"
```

treafik.toml

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[api]

[docker]
  domain = "xyz.nl"
  exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
  email = "jj@xyz.nl"
  storage = "acme.json"
  onHostRule = true
  entryPoint = "https"
  onDemand = false
  [acme.tlsChallenge]
```

I recommend to not mix CLI args and TOML for the same section (ex: `--docker` and `[docker]`)

Comment: I made the changes. Thank you. Alas, no result. I have put the results of the changes the after 'UPDATE' key word of my question.